# How to add borders around navigation labels?

Tags: css

Consider this HTML:

```html
<li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
```

I would like to know how I can add borders around each button in a light blue or blue color.

Comment: Sorry i phrased the question wrongly

Comment: There is already bottom border

Comment: @Omi where is the bottom border you mention?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it by a few ways.
1st does the ul or ol the li belong  too have a class name like

```
<ul class = "name">
   <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: <div class="container">
<div class="header clearfix">

Comment: try .nav-pills a{
  border: 1px blue solid;
} and tell me if it works

Comment: i tried it and nothing occurs.  do i need to delete something.  Really sorry im a total beginner at this

Comment: No worries can you please post the code with the ul and the div they belong too

Comment: <div class="container">
<div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
         <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

Comment: nav a{
  border:2px solid lightblue;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
nav li{
  display:inline-block;
}

Comment: Is this what you want

Comment: Now if case you have an other nav then you can do it via class .header a{
  border:2px solid lightblue;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.header li{
  display:inline-block;
}

Comment: ok ill have a go.  I think i will get go to the page austin suggested at w3schools and get lessons

Comment: You add this to your css file if you do not have access to the css file or you dont have one. then add inside the head <style> .header a{
  border:2px solid lightblue;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.header li{
  display:inline-block;
}</style>

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a border to the `a` element and with padding make it farther away from the words. Displaying the `li` elements as inline block will make them stay on the same line. Since I added the border on the `a` element, that means that the whole area inside the border is clickable.

```css
a{
  border:2px solid lightblue;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, just add the following rule:

```
a {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

And here is the snippet:

```css
a {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this but where do i add it in the code before the <ul>

Comment: At that place, where your code from the answer is. I just wrapped all `li`s in `ul` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I've sorted it out just now thanks to morpheous

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

You should be able to add the following code in your CSS.

```css
ul li {
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Border</li>
  <li>Bottom</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
</ul>
```

You can change the border attributes. ie

```css
ul li {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Border</li>
  <li>Bottom</li>
  <li>Green</li>
</ul>
```

etc.

You can make other styling changes but your question the "border-bottom" attribute might be what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Reference this guide here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

add a class to all of the buttons and add border attributes to it.

In your html file

```
<a href="index.php" class="border">
```

In your style file (or styles in header)

```
.border{border: 2px solid #0000FF;}
```

You could also do this inline but head over to w3schools to learn about that

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle that might help: https://jsfiddle.net/9mmf3omc/1/

html

```
  <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
```

css

```
li {
  display: inline-block;   # necessary to format links/buttons correctly
  margin: 10px 0;
}

li a {
  border: 1px solid blue;  # adds blue border around link/button
  padding: 10px;           # gives some room between text and border
  text-decoration: none;   # removes underlined link if you prefer
}
```

As for border colors, check out one of many color-picker tools like [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool) and make the border any shade of blue you want.  Just change:

```
border: 1px solid blue;
```

to say,

```
border: 1px solid #88EBFB;
```

Comment: glad to help.  I added comments to explain the what the additional styling does.